# Complex fields and action in electrodynamics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, action, greens-functions, propagator

The interaction action in QED is
$$
S_{\text{int}} = \int j^\mu (x) \delta_+((x-y)^2) j_\mu(y) d^4 x d^4 y
$$
where $\delta_+(x) = \delta(x) - \frac{i}{\pi x}$ is the photon propagator.

This expression is given in many places, e.g. *QED and the Men Who Made It* page 423. It is what you'd expect to get from the path integral formulation of QED.

I have two issues with it however. Firstly, since the propagator is complex, the action will be complex, and I assumed this would not be allowed.

Second, one would expect a form schematically like $A^\mu j_\mu$ in the action and so I am tempted to say that
$$
A^\mu(x) = \int \delta_+((x-y)^2) j^\mu(y) d^4 y,
$$
which reduces to
$$
A^\mu(x) = \int j^\mu(y)\frac{1}{2R} \left( \delta_+(t-R) + \delta_+(t+R) \right) d^4 y,
$$
where I defined $t = x^0-y^0$, $R = |\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|$.
If I ignore the $1/x$ part in the $\delta_+$, then I get the beautiful and I think correct result
$$
A_\mu(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( A_{\mu}^{\text{advanced}} + A_{\mu}^{\text{retarded}} \right) ,
$$
where
$$
A_\mu^{\text{adv.}/\text{ret.}} = \int j_\mu(y)\frac{1}{2R}\delta(t\pm R) d^4 y.
$$

However, there are extra bits due to the $1/x$ part of $\delta_+$ and I would have a complex and acausal field
$$
A_\mu^{\text{adv.}/\text{ret.}} = \int j_\mu(y)\frac{1}{2R}\delta(t\pm R) d^4 y \mp \frac{i}{\pi} \int j_\mu(y)\frac{1}{2R (t \pm R)} d^4 y.
$$
I would like to perform a gauge transformation to eliminate that imaginary part but I know that can't work because it would also have to change the action. What's going on here?